# Reverse Every K Nodes

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Every k nodes form a segment. If the last few nodes are less than K, then you can ignore them.
Write a reverseKnodes() which reserves every segment in the linked list.
The function prototype is given as follow: void reversekNodes(ListNode** head, int k);

Input format:
The 1st line is the k
The 2nd line is the data to create the linked list and ends with a non-digit symbol Example:
Input: 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 a
Output: 3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7 10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _listNode
{
  int item;
  struct _listNode *next;
};
typedef struct _listNode ListNode;

void printList (ListNode * head);
void deleteList (ListNode ** ptrHead);
void reverseKNodes (ListNode ** head, int K);

int
main ()
{
  ListNode *head = NULL, *temp;
  int i = 0;
  int K = 0;

  scanf ("%d", &K);

  while (scanf ("%d", &i))
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = (ListNode *) malloc (sizeof (ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = (ListNode *) malloc (sizeof (ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = i;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;


    reverseKNodes (&head, K);
    printList (head);
    deleteList (&head);
    return 0;
}

void
printList (ListNode * head)
{

  while (head != NULL)
    {

      printf ("%d ", head->item);

      head = head->next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

void
deleteList (ListNode ** ptrHead)
{

  ListNode *cur = *ptrHead;

  ListNode *temp;

  while (cur != NULL)
    {

      temp = cur->next;

      free (cur);

      cur = temp;
    }
    *ptrHead = NULL;
}

void
reverseKNodes (ListNode ** head, int K)
{

struct _listNode *reverse (struct _listNode *head, int k){
if (!head)
return NULL;
struct _listNode* cur = head;
struct _listNode* next = NULL;
struct _listNode* prev = NULL;
int count = 0;

while (cur != NULL && count < K)
{
next = cur->next;
cur->next = prev;
prev = cur;
cur = next;
count++;
}


if (next != NULL)
head->next = reverse(next, K);

return prev;
}
}
```

I am not allowed to change anything else other than the void function for reverseKNodes and I know I have done it wrong but I dont know where I went wrong. Could someone help me please?

Comment: `while (scanf ("%d", &i))` will never exits.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED homework is definitely allowed, what is not allowed is posting the question with no attempt at an answe. THis question has code written by OP. So this is fine

Comment: pm100: Even if so, we'll move on to the next issue then. No debugging details were provided - no attempt was made to diagnose the problem. This is definitely closeable as is.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with nested functions ...

1. Nested functions aren't standard C.
2. Are of limited benefit.
3. They add extra overhead to invoke.
4. So [please] don't use them.
5. And, your usage of one is incorrect. In `reverseKNodes`, you *define* `reverse` but never *call* it. So, `reverseKNodes` is a no-op.

So, to fix, move `reverse` out of the body of `reverseKNodes` and place it above. Then, actually invoke it in `reverseKNodes`:

```
void
reverseKNodes(ListNode **head, int K)
{

    *head = reverse(*head, K);
}
```

---

Here is the full refactored code. For aid in debug (e.g. with `gdb`), I added code to allow the program to take an input file as an argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _listNode {
    int item;
    struct _listNode *next;
};
typedef struct _listNode ListNode;

void printList(ListNode *head);
void deleteList(ListNode **ptrHead);
void reverseKNodes(ListNode **head, int K);

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    ListNode *head = NULL, *temp;
    int i = 0;
    int K = 0;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    FILE *xf;
    do {
        if (argc != 1) {
            xf = stdin;
            break;
        }

        xf = fopen(*argv,"r");
        if (xf != NULL)
            break;

        perror(*argv);
        exit(1);
    } while (0);

    fscanf(xf,"%d", &K);

    while (fscanf(xf,"%d", &i)) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = (ListNode *) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = (ListNode *) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = i;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;

    reverseKNodes(&head, K);
    printList(head);
    deleteList(&head);
    return 0;
}

void
printList(ListNode *head)
{

    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void
deleteList(ListNode **ptrHead)
{

    ListNode *cur = *ptrHead;

    ListNode *temp;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        temp = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        cur = temp;
    }

    *ptrHead = NULL;
}

struct _listNode *
reverse(struct _listNode *head, int K)
{

    if (! head)
        return NULL;

    struct _listNode *cur = head;
    struct _listNode *next = NULL;
    struct _listNode *prev = NULL;

    int count = 0;

    while (cur != NULL && count < K) {
        next = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;

        prev = cur;
        cur = next;

        count++;
    }

    if (next != NULL)
        head->next = reverse(next, K);

    return prev;
}

void
reverseKNodes(ListNode **head, int K)
{

    *head = reverse(*head, K);
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7 10
```